# Invoke/Integrate SoapUI to an Automation Regression Test Project

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, integration-testing, soapui

We are using SoapUI for firing web services.
Now, I'm creating an automation regression test project(Java, Maven, Selenium Webdirver). There are many test suites need SoapUI to send web service request at the beginning or in the middle of the test. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can import SoapUI source code or install SoapUI jars to my project. So I can call SoapUI functions or methods or classes directly.
I've added these dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jgoodies</groupId>
    <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.squirrel-sql.thirdparty-non-maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>com-fifesoft-rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.eik.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I also installed SoapUI Intellij Idea Plugin. But seems nothing changed.
Thank you for any help and advice. Or if there is any other approach to implementing this feature will be great as well.

Comment: This is too broad. You need to narrow down the issue with specifics.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to know what preparation works do I have to do? So I can use soapUI source code's method directly.

Comment: Agree with @Rao Maybe start with the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html

Comment: Got the answer from SmartBear community. Import all the jars and soapUI jar to my project. Sorry, maybe it is my bad, I didn't descript very clearly. I just want to run soapUI through my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import all the soapUi jars and SoapUI.jar from C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\lib and C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin.

```
public void runTestCase(String tarSuite, String tarCase) throws Exception {

    String reportStr = "";

    SoapUI.setSoapUICore(new StandaloneSoapUICore(true));

    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("C:\\Users\\tshi\\Documents\\Maven Projects\\ASORT\\WebServiceResource\\Suncorp_Issuing-soapui-project.xml");

    List<TestSuite> suiteList = project.getTestSuiteList();

    for (TestSuite aSuiteList : suiteList) {

        String suiteName = aSuiteList.getName();

        List<TestCase> caseList = aSuiteList.getTestCaseList();
        //System.out.println("Test Suite: " + suiteName);

        if (suiteName.equals(tarSuite)) {

            for (TestCase aCaseList : caseList) {

                String caseName = aCaseList.getName();
                //System.out.println("Test Case: " + caseName);

                if (caseName.equals(tarCase)) {

                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    TestRunner runner = project.getTestSuiteByName(suiteName).getTestCaseByName(caseName).run(new PropertiesMap(), false);

                    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                    reportStr = reportStr + "\n\tTestCase: " + aCaseList.getName() + "\tStatus: " + runner.getStatus() + "\tReason: " + runner.getReason() + "\tDuration: " + duration;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    System.out.print(reportStr);

}
```

This may not be the best way to achieve the goal. But it actually works for me. All the devices will be welcome. Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you trying to run soapUI through maven. If that is so, you pom.xml should contain `soapui-maven-plugin` and `pluginRepository` . So your pom.xml should look like below. It also includes `maven-surefire-report-plugin` to get an HTML type report. you will have to change `<projectFile>sample-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>`
 to include your project file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>mytest</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mytest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
      <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
      <url>http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
   </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
  <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.2-m-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <configuration>
    <!--soapUI project file location-->
    <projectFile>sample-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
    <!--output file location-->
    <outputFolder>${project.basedir}/output/</outputFolder>
    <!--junit results file-->
    <junitReport>true</junitReport>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>soapUI</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```